# Does this integral converge $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}\,dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

> I need to check whether this integral converges or not $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}\,dx$

I substituted $y=-x$ then this integral transformed to  $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{e^{y}}{1+y^2}\,dy$ , then I thought of dividing it into two parts from $-\infty$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $\infty$, in the first case I think area will be finite but in the second case it's not since $e^x$ grows rapidly, so it diverges!

Comment: I could not follow your statement "I substituted $y=−x$ then this integral transformed to $\int \frac{e^y} {1+y^2}dx$ ,"

Comment: It doesn't converge. For $x\to -\infty$, the factor $e^{-x}$ grows exponentially (well, how else ;).

Comment: plot the graph, convince yourself, that it diverges

Comment: Have you a course of complex analysis Neeraj? You may try it using calculus of residue.

Comment: @Samprity no complex analysis yet!

Comment: TIFR GS2012 Prob. 24. I shall try to write an easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Check $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}$. Are both zero? If not, then this implies that the integral does not converge (since the integrand is strictly positive, we can't have cancellation as in the $\sin(x^2)$ case).

Comment: To be completely clear, the integrand doesn't necessarily have to converge to 0, but if it converges to something, it must be zero for the integral to converge.

Comment: @egreg: I may be mistaken, but no it's not. Consider a function that makes increasingly narrow triangles but with constant height.

Comment: @nik: You are correct. Thank you for making it more explicit. Fortunately, here both do converge (in the extended real numbers sense).

Comment: @nik I think you're right; the correct argument should be that *this* function is monotone in a neighborhood of $\infty$ and of $-\infty$.

Comment: @Clayton: Yes, your answer is fine; I'm just making clear all the details for the OP.

Comment: @egreg Note that there are positive unbounded functions $f$ such that $$\int f(x)\,dx<\infty $$ Consider a "sum of spikes" function such that $f(n)=n$ on while small otherwise.

Comment: @AD. Yes, I realized that and removed my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : You first calculate  $$\int_a^b \frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}dx$$

and then send $b\rightarrow \infty$ and $a\rightarrow -\infty$.

If this limit exists then, your integral converges.

Comment: why negative vote :O

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but calculating that integral is hard. Deciding convergence is easy. In other words this answer is no real help.

Comment: @AD. Oh.. yes... I could not realize that before.. Thank you for mentioning that.. :)